# How to make RSA encryption/decryption/cracking (SIMPLE) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rsa

I've made a python code that encrypts, decrypts and "cracks" using RSA. The purpose of the code is to compare how long it takes my computer to crack different levels of RSA encryption by changing the digits of the prime numbers. The code works fine but I'm not sure if I've used the right math and variables to calculate the keys and so on. Can someone please check for any mistakes and in case of mistakes help me fix them? This is for a school project so I really want to do this right. Feel free to come with suggestions to how I can optimize the code to run better/more efficiently.

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import time
from sympy import isprime
from sympy import primerange
from itertools import combinations

#Functions
def ascii(word):
    return [ord(char) for char in word]

def euclid(a,b):
    return (1-a*euclid(b, a%b))/b%a if b else 0


#Message
msg = "H"
lowerprime = 90000
higherprime = 100000

#Variables
p=0
q=0
e=0
d=0

#Code
primes = sorted(primerange(lowerprime, higherprime))
p, q = random.sample(primes, 2)    
n = p*q
phi = (p-1)*(q-1)

while e == d:
    while math.gcd(e, phi) != 1:
        e = random.randint(2, phi-1)
    d = int(euclid(phi, e))

int(e)

print("p = %i q = %i" % (p, q))
print("n = %i" % (n))
print("phi = %i" % (phi))
print("e = %i" % (e))
print("d = %i" % (d))
print("Msg: %s" % msg)
print("Asciimsg: %s" % ascii(msg))

#keygenerator
for asciiMsgInt in ascii(msg):
    encrypted = pow(asciiMsgInt, e, n)
    print("Encrypted message: %i" % encrypted)

    decrypted = np.int64(pow(encrypted, d, n))
    print("Decrypted message: %s" % chr(decrypted))


#cracker
start_time = time.time()
crack=0
gcdcounter=0

for pcrack, qcrack in ((p,q) for p,q in combinations(primes,2) if p*q==n):
    phicrack = (pcrack-1)*(qcrack-1)
    ecrack=0
    gcdcounter=gcdcounter+1
    print("GCDcounter: %i" % gcdcounter)
    for ecrack in range(2, int(phicrack)):
        if ecrack == e:
            print("pcrack: %i" % pcrack)
            print("qcrack: %i" % qcrack)
            print("Ecrack: %i" % ecrack)
            dcrack = int(euclid(phicrack, ecrack))
            print("Dcrack: %i" % dcrack)

runTime = (time.time() - start_time)
print("Time: %s" % runTime)
```

Comment: Maybe try [codereview.se]. The way to test your code is to test it against answers that you independently know (either because you have worked it out by hand or because it is from an authoritative source). Your question is a bit to unfocused for Stack Overflow. It is unlikely that anyone is going to spend the time needed to look over your code because it *might* contain an error. You are essentially asking for someone to perform a service for you rather than asking an actual question.

Comment: Nothing in cryptography is "simple".